# check if two div HTML elements intersect

Tags: javascript

How to check if two div HTML elements intersect/overlap/touch each other?

- The two divs are fixed at the X axis so they can only move up and down

I got both `top` and `bottom` positions for both div elements

Answer (score 0):

If you already have both `top` and `bottom`, then it's just a conditional:

```
if ((top1 <= top2 && bottom1 >= top2) || (top2 <= top1 && bottom2 >= top1)) {
    // intersect/overlap/touch
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to consider the element height, as well as their offsets.
Then it's just a matter of checking:

1. Which one is is closer to the top (top1>top2)? Realize that if you have the offset of the divs, you will have to check which one is closer to 0.
2. Check if the value from TOPMOST_TOP_VALUE+TOPMOST_DIV_HEIGHT > top2.

If condition 2 is true, you have intersecting divs.

Hope I could help.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you assign them some size (width, height and border). Also you can use UI debugger (by using F12 key) to see actually where those are located.